# How to strip a 2d array in python Numpy Array?

Tags: python, numpy, strip

Suppose i have an np array like this-

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```

I want a function fun_strip(x) . After applying this function i want the returned array to look like this:

```
[[ 6  7  8]
 [11 12 13]]
```

Comment: it it nott clear by wich principle you want to select the elments of thee new array, can you please explain

Comment: `def strip(arr): return np.array([[6,7,8],[11,12,13]])`. Unless you wish to specify another constraint. Definition of what you want by a sole example may lead to perfectly correct answer that don't fit your real need. Like mine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove 1 value on each border?

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

out = a[1:a.shape[0]-1, 1:a.shape[1]-1]
```

Generalization for `N`:

```
N = 1
a[N:a.shape[0]-N, N:a.shape[1]-N]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a simpler `a[1:-1, 1:-1]`?

Comment: Thanks this is the solve i was trying to figure out.

Comment: @dm2 in case N=0, but for N>0 you're right it's more simple

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example:

```
arr = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                [5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
arr[1:3, 1:4]
```

Strip function in general:

```
def strip_func(arr, r1, r2, c1, c2):
   return(arr[r1:r2+1, c1:c2+1])
```

`r1` and `r2` is the beginning and end of the range of rows that you want to subset. `c1` and `c2` is the same but for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works only for the specified use case would be:

```
def fun_strip(array):
    return np.array([array[1][1:4],array[2][1:4]])
```

You need to specify better what the use case is if you want a better, general implementation

Comment: @ShahidaYeasmin you may want to edit your question to say that, then. As is, you haven't said at all what is the task.

Comment: Sincerely apologize to give less information in my questions. and thanks for your support.